# How to find a file recusively in children directories?

Tags: find-file

How to find a file recursively in children? Like the opposite of `locate-dominating-file` (`locate-dominating-file` finds file recursively in its parent directory)?

Comment: In newer emacs versions there is [`directory-files-recursively`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Contents-of-Directories.html). That's sufficient for most jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Library [**`find-dired+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/find-dired%2b.el) is an extension of standard library `find-dired.el`.  It offers a few `find` commands that can help:

- `find-dired`, `find-name-dired`, `find-grep-dired` - Like the standard commands, but with optional args to limit depth and exclude specified paths.
- `find-time-dired` - Find files newer or older than a given timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find-lisp-find-files` from `find-lisp.el`.

`find-lisp-find-files` takes two arguments: `directory-to-search-from` and `regexp-of-file-that-you-want-to-search`

`(defun find-lisp-find-files (directory regexp) ...)`

It returns a list of files that match the regexp if found, else it returns nil.

Comment: Could you show a snippet that uses it?